# localstorage not setting value when in playwright global setup

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

I am attempting to load local storage in global.setup.js in Playwright Test. The code runs with no issues, but the local storage is empty. This is not a issue if I place the code in a beforeEach block, but I rather have it in global set up. Anyone know why the local storage is empty when using it in global.setup.js?

global.setup.js

```
const { chromium } = require('@playwright/test');
  
  const createOktaInjection = async(page) => {
    const idToken = 'foobar';
    const accessToken = 'foobar';
  
    const mockToken = {
      idToken: {
        idToken,
      },
      accessToken: {
        accessToken,
      },
    }
  
    const pagePromise = page.addInitScript(params => {
      window.localStorage.setItem(params.name, params.value);
    },
    {
      name: 'okta-token-storage',
      value: JSON.stringify(mockToken),
    });
  
    return pagePromise;
  };
  
  module.exports = async() => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    return createOktaInjection(page);
  };
```

playwright.config.js

```
  export default defineConfig({
    testDir: './tests',
    fullyParallel: true,
    /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
    forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
    /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
    workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
    reporter: 'html',
    use: {
      baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
      //trace: 'retain-on-failure',
      launchOptions: {
        slowMo: slowMoTime || 900,
        devtools: true,
      },
    },
  
    projects: [
      {
        name: 'setup',
        testMatch: /global.setup\.js/,
      },
      {
        name: 'chromium',
        use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
        dependencies: ['setup'],
      },
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `localStorage` is not preserved across different instances of the `Page` class in Playwright. When you set the `localStorage` in the `global.setup.js`, you're setting it for that specific Page instance. But when the tests run, they'll likely be using a completely different `Page` instance, which won't have that `localStorage` data. I cannot tell this for sure, but seems likely based on everything you've described.

The global setup script is usually used for starting/stopping services that are needed by your tests (like a mock API server), or setting global test configuration, rather than interacting with a Page.

However, you can use the [`beforeEach`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-before-each) block to set the local storage for each test file or each test as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this and created a test fixture

```
export function enableIsE2eTestingInProgress(
  baseToExtend: TestType<PlaywrightTestArgs & PlaywrightTestOptions, PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions>
) {
  return baseToExtend.extend({
    page: async ({ page }, use) => {
      await page.addInitScript(params => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("IS_E2E_TESTING_IN_PROGRESS", 'true');
      });

      await use(page);
    },
  });
}
```

Useful to disable "new relic" or parts of a single page application using a testingService with `!environment.production`.  You don't want to change the behavior of the application when under test, but in some cases it makes sense to.